# How to get Full Route History from useHistory in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history, breadcrumbs

I am working on useHistory() hook. I need to fill the breadcrumbs from the useHistory route. I need to fill the breadcrumbs from where we came to home page or '/'.I don't know how to do it using useHistory.I know only few methods like goBack(). But it gives only the previous route. I need the whole history stack. Is there any way to get that in react?

Comment: https://medium.com/@mattywilliams/generating-an-automatic-breadcrumb-in-react-router-fed01af1fc3

Comment: I dont want this.I want to print useStory Stack,so that I can loop over it

Answer (score 1):

**For creating a breadcrumb, you could be making use of history's location object**

Something like this:

```
function DashboardDetail() {
  const history = useHistory();

  const { pathname } = history.location;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>BreadCrumb: {pathname.split("/").join(" -> ")}</p>
      <h2>Dashboard Detail</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working Example:

[image: Edit React Router - BreadCrumb]

Comment: I need to get histort stack,i am getting the length of the stack of history,but not the elements of it.Any idea of it

Comment: On any current page, history only contains the path. If you want to have the complete elements of them. I think you will need to loop through it and map the name with the actual element itself

Comment: You are taking it the wrong way. If you print history, it will show different properties, among these is the length property which gives how many URLs are there in the history stack, I am getting that length. But not the actual URLs that are there in the stack

Comment: will you please show how to map history

Comment: What history do you mean to map? Not a pure string URL of each visited path?

Comment: I want the history of URL's of all visited pages